# Array of Objects conditional style in textarea. Angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, web

I have an array of objects like this:

```
   list =[  
   {  
      name:"name1",
      value:true
   }   {  
      name:"name2",
      value:false
   }   {  
      name:"name3",
      value:true
   }   {  
      name:"name4",
      value:false
   }
]
```

What I want to do is to show inside a text area all objects names and if object.value is false underline or bold the line. And then to be able to write inside the text area to remove the underlined elements.

What I tried was:

```
<textarea *ngFor="let item of list" [ngClass]="{cssClass: item.value==false}">
{{item.name}}
</textarea>
```

-The problem here is that it shows an empty text area for each object
AND

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list" [ngClass]="{cssClass: item.value==false}">
<textarea>
{{item.name}}
</textarea>
</div>
```

The problem here is that it creates a textarea per line, where the line is inside.

Comment: try this `<textarea><p *ngFor="let item of list" [ngClass]="{cssClass: item.value==false}">
{{item.name}}</p>
</textarea>`

Comment: You can use `[class.cssClass]="item.value==false"`

Comment: You can also try `[ngClass]="{'cssClass': item.value==false}"` OR directly set `true` OR `false` to confirm the working of the code `[ngClass]="{'cssClass': true}"`

Answer (score 1):

You have string value not the the boolean type. So you should use string value `'true'` or `'false'` not `true` and `false`.

```
<textarea *ngFor="let item of list" [ngClass]="{cssClass: item.value=='false'}">
```

### OR

If you have option to modify the object then change the value type as -

```
  list =[  
   {  
      name:"name1",
      value:true
   }   {  
      name:"name2",
      value:false
   }   {  
      name:"name3",
      value:true
   }   {  
      name:"name4",
      value:false
   }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem. The problem is about the loop to show the all lines just in one textarea.

With that ngFor what I'm getting is one textarea by each line.

Comment: In that case you should iterate over the array in `ts` file  and get the complete appended text and display that appended text in textarea. Do note that you cannot  underline and bold the content inside the textarea.